# Unable to float Form and icon left

Tags: html, css, forms

I've recently decided to do an in-depth understanding of HTML (I mean not just slapping bootstrap all over the place). I've been trying to create an HTML page with just styling with CSS. I've recently been unable to float the input column to sit just opposite the image icon. Every time I try to float left the icon and input div to lay next to the icon, the form breaks and fails to move. Here's my code below;

(The elements required to lay side by side are colored green)

I appreciate any help

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

.clr-fix{
    clear: both;
}
#main-header {
    background: #333;
}
#image-size, #query-items{
    float: left;
       
}
#main-header #image-size{
    background: green;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main-header #query-items{
    background: green; 
    clear: right;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main-header #image-size #DDCG-logo{
    width: 117px;
    height: 25px;
}

.container #sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
}

.container #sidebar ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.container #sidebar ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1    px solid white;
}
#table-display{
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#table{
    
    background: #333;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>DCCG Cell Locator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ListingPage.css" `>
    <link rel="icon" href="Images/Favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header id="main-header">
            <div id="image-size">
                <img id = 'DDCG-logo' src="Images/html-imgs/Daystar-Christian-Centre.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="clr-fix"></div>
            
            <div id="query-items">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                <input id="add-search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for addresses...">
            </div>
            
        </header>

    </div>
    <div class="clr-fix"></div>
    <div class=container>
        <section id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>About Us</li>
                <li>Announcement</li>
                <li>Offering</li>
                <li>Resources</li>
                <li>Watch Us Online</li>

            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class=container>
        <div id="table-display">
            <div id="table">
                <div id="table-head">
                    <h1>Daystar Cell Locator</h1>
                </div>
                <section id="main-area">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Var 1</th>
                                <th>Var 2</th>
                                <th> Var 3</th>
                                <th> Var 4</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbodY>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbodY>
                    </table>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <footer id="main footer">
            <p>All copyrights &copy DayStar Christian Centre. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would be nice of you to reduce the code cruft to a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as you are/were supposed to. Would be much easier for us to sift through your code

Comment: what is your desire page?

Comment: Noted Rawrplus will do in future

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe you need to adjust the div sizes. By default, div tags take up 100% width, even if they don't use any of it. If they are both set at default then there is no room for one of them to float over for the other.

EDIT: I see you did adjust the size of the "image-size" tag, but your search bar div looks to still be default.

EDIT 2: I got it working on my end. Here's what I did:

1. Removed .clr-fix.
2. only float #image-size left
3. reduce #query-items at or below 75% width
4. remove display: inline-block

Comment: Thanks HKRob. Honestly I didn't even expect to be answered. Appreciate it